# How to center image of variable width in DIV on page?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have an image of variable width that I'd like to center in a container `div`, which will be centered on the page.

If I set a width on the `div` and give it a `margin: 0 auto`, it will center, but the problem is that the image inside of the `div` is of variable width, so I can't set a width on the container `div`.

Any suggestions?

**Clarification:** The container `div` has a background image that needs to expand 30px on either side of the image. Because of that, the container `div` needs to be of a set width but be able to expand/contract based on the image size.

Comment: what's the purpose of the div? Is it a visual element?(for framing) I think the only way you will be able to set the width is via JS or other script

Comment: @Moak, it's a visual element for framing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add padding to the image!

```
img#foo{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:url(/image/bg.gif);
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Oh, good idea to just add that to the image. The `div` was kind of unnecessary I guess. Thanks Moak!

Answer (score 3):

```
img#foo {
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

An image element is a replaced element and its intrinsic width will allow it to be centered without an explicit width set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting image as background and center it would work?

Comment: See my clarification above. Thanks.